# Custom Quick Action for Flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

How can I create a new quickaction for a custom object to be used in this flow?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Specifically, you should tell us what you have tried so far (use [edit], not comments)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that in order to create a new quickaction you must either create a global action or object specific action. Please be aware you will need  to refresh your flow in order to view the newly created action ( I initially had kept flow builder open and the new action was not fetched!)